# Foreign Keys in Embeddable Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String technicalName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;
}

@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}

@Embeddable
public class Permission {

    private Country country;    

    private Role role;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Permissions")
    private Set<Permission> permissions;
}
```

The User_Permissions table should look like this:

```
+------------+-------------+-----+
| Field      | Type        | Key |
+------------+-------------+-----+
| user_id    | int(10)     | FK  |
| role_id    | int(10)     | FK  |
| country_id | int(10)     | FK  |
+------------+-------------+-----+
```

I'm using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto for testing. When I'm deploying my application I'm getting this error:

```
Could not determine type for: 
Country, at table: User_Permissions, for columns: 
[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(country)]
```

I could model it with a @OneToMany but from my point of view Permission is not an entity but a value type, because it provides meaning to the User entity but not to itself.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The problem is not Permission. The problem is Permission.country, and Permission.role. You haven't specified any mapping for them, but they should be ManyToOne.

Comment: Wow sir, you made my day. Thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark your comment as the solution, so if you want the credits for that I would ask you to post your comment as an actual answer.